# Unhashable Type Error Whilst Finding Mode

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to write a Python function `one_mode(l)` that takes a non-empty list `l` and returns a pair with its mode and the frequency of the mode. (In case there are several modes, an arbitrary one can be returned.)

So far I have...

```
from scipy import stats
def one_mode(l):
    return stats.mode(l)
```

which works for the followings tests:

```
one_mode([5, 6, 7, 5]) == (5,2)
```

But not for the test:

```
one_mode([5, 6, 7, 5, 6]) in {(5, 2), (6, 2)}
```

In this case it gives me

> unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Is there any way around this using my current code?

Comment: try using a `list`, not a `set`. So that's `[(5, 2), (6, 2)]`

Comment: or convert `one_model(l)` into a plain tuple (which will be hashable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you force the results of `stats.mode` to a tuple, your lookup will work:

**Code:**

```
from scipy import stats
def one_mode(l):
    mode = stats.mode(l)

    # return first mode results as tuple
    return mode[0][0], mode[1][0]
```

**Test Code:**

```
assert one_mode([5, 6, 7, 5]) == (5, 2)
assert one_mode([5, 6, 7, 5, 6]) in {(5, 2), (6, 2)}
```